# How can I change the order of libraries in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, libraries

I have documents, music, pictures and videos by default and added 'dropbox'. 
They are sorted in alphabetical order.
How can I change this order?

Comment: What order do you want? Size, Date Created, Date Modified or random?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort them as they appear in the window right click and select "sort by" in the context menu.

If you mean you want to change them as they appear in the pane to the left of the window, as far as I know this can only be done through a registry edit which can lead to unintended adverse effects so you're pretty much stuck with alphabetical.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your options to order things are the standard 'name' 'date modified' 'type' etc. (without registry modification or third-party shell tools).

If you want them to display in a custom order the easiest thing to do is to rename your existing libraries so that the alphanumeric sort takes care of it for you.

```
1 - Pictures
2 - Dropbox
3 - Videos
4 - Pictures
```